# base64_encode(file_get_contents(zipPath)) c# equivalent

Tags: c#

I have this php function

```
base64_encode(file_get_contents($this->pathZIP));
```

it returns a Zip Base64 Bytes and need to port it to c#

What is the exact equivalent in c#?

Comment: [Convert.ToBase64String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string) + [File.ReadAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes) + [ZipFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile) Class

Comment: You can also return a Stream from `[ZipArchiveEntry].Open()`, write to a MemoryStream and return the `[MemoryStream].ToArray()` bytes for the encoding part.

Comment: ← if you want to extract a file from zip archive and return the base64String of it. Otherwise (since `file_get_contents` reads the content of file as a string), just `string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes([ATextFilePath));`

Comment: Tks. My file isn't a txt file, it its a zipped file.

Comment: So, do you want to extract a Text file from a zipped archive and convert the content to a base64 string? Is it actually a Text file? Does your zip file contain just one file (in whatever format) or you need to extract and encode more than one file/all files and encode them all? Or do you want to actually encode the zip archive itself?

Answer (score 2):

Try one:

```
Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("path");
String file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not completely clear what is the actual task this method should perform, here's a *configurable* method that accept an argument, used to specify what files to extract from a zipped archive and then convert to Base64 strings (no matter what the file type). It should be easy to extend, in case other types of selections are needed (using wildcards/file extensions, maybe).

You can specify to return:

1. The first file found in the archive
2. All files in the archive
3. A selection of files, passing to the method a collection of strings that includes the file names

<sub>**Extract and encode the first file found in the zipped archive**:</sub>

```
string zipFilePath = [The Zip file Path];
var base64Results = UnzipToBase64String(zipFilePath, null, UnZipOptions.FirstFile);
```

<sub>**All files**:</sub>

```
var base64Results = UnzipToBase64String(zipFilePath, null, UnZipOptions.AllFiles);
```

<sub>**A selection of files**:</sub>

```
string[] fileList = { "File1.txt", "File2.exe", "File3.dll", "File4.pdf" };
var base64Results = UnzipToBase64String(zipFilePath, fileList, UnZipOptions.ListOfFiles);
```

In case you just wanted to encode the zip archive itself:

```
 string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes([The Archive Path]));
```

Convert to `byte[]` if needed (for any of the above):

```
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64);
```

---

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO; 
using System.IO.Compression;

public enum UnZipOptions
{
    AllFiles,
    FirstFile,
    ListOfFiles
}

public IEnumerable<string> UnzipToBase64String(string archivePath, IEnumerable<string> fileList, UnZipOptions options)
{
    if (options == UnZipOptions.ListOfFiles && (fileList == null | fileList.Count() == 0)) yield break;

    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(File.OpenRead(archivePath))) {
        foreach(ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries) {
            if (options == UnZipOptions.ListOfFiles && 
                !fileList.Contains(entry.Name, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                continue;
            using (Stream stream = entry.Open())
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                stream.CopyTo(ms);
                ms.Position = 0;
                yield return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                if (options == UnZipOptions.FirstFile) {
                    yield break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi tks for your help. I need to send entire file to a WCF service using autogenerated c# client, my problem is the file sent cause an exception at server when it try to process that file. What I am trying to do is use equivalent functions that works at PHP client.

Comment: Right. But `file_get_contents` reads a file as a **string**. If `$this->pathZIP` is a path to a `zip` archive, you cannot read it as a string, since it's a binary file. In C#, as already described, you use, `string base64Encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes([The Archive Path]));`. Now, `base64Encoded` represents the **zip file archive bytes** encoded as a Base64 string. On the other side, a C# code would look like: `File.WriteAllBytes([The Archive Path], Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded));`. You didn't mention the exception you receive.

Comment: What is the *other side* expecting? A binary file or a text file?

Comment: Other side is a black box the only thing I have is the wsdl service definition **<xs:element name="contentFile" type="xs:base64Binary" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>**, C# client expects **byte[]** as parameter.

Comment: `type="xs:base64binary"` expects binary data encoded as a base64String, so this: `string base64Encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes([The Archive Path]));`. This will send the whole **zip achive file** as a base64String (quite commonly used to embed binary data in HTML pages, for example). I don't know what the  `C# client` is and how your code is supposed to interact with it. What bytes is it expecting? The base64 string transferred as bytes or the bytes that represent the binary file? Or a Stream? Your question is lacking a whole lot of details.

Comment: c# Client is an autogenerated client for  WCF service based on wsdl definition **:(**, My question here is about that things I was trying to do to solve that exception at BLACKBOX service. tks a lot  for tour help. **:'(**

Comment: You can also try to pass `var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64Encoded);`. Now the `bytes` array contains the string representation as bytes; try to pass this to the client. -- A base64 String is represented only by ASCII chars, so you can use both `Encoding.UTF8` or `Encoding.ASCII`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205898/discussion-between-juan-pablo-gomez-and-jimi).